# Out-of-screen list tiles handling

Tags: dart, flutter

I am new to flutter and I want to know if there are any event listeners or methods to process off-screen tiles, thank you.

Comment: can you provide some more context? How are your tiles going off the screen? Are you using a `Dismissible`?

Comment: no, I am just using List.builder to generate the tiles dynamically as outlined in flutter cookbook [link](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists)

Comment: so.. what kind of processing do you need to do on your off-screen tiles?

Comment: I am trying to unitialize some objects when out of view so I can free the device memory: video processing